# Disable specific date in DateTimePicker

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetimepicker

I was wondering if I can disable dates on the DateTimePicker when the date is in the MySQL database? Is it possible?

Comment: The WinForms `DateTimePicker` control doesn't support disabling specific dates. All you can do is validate the input, which you would do in the `Validating` event handler, and test for a match to a list of disallowed dates. You could test a list you created earlier or you could query the database with the current value.

Comment: @jmcilhinney can you show me a sample on how it is done? I'm just a beginner.

Comment: @jmcilhinney okay. I'm sorry. I've been trying to search a way on how it is done before and after I asked here. Anyway, thanks.